# Huge difference in performances between GRUs and LSTMs. How is it possible?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, gru

I'm currently working on a Polyphonic Sound Event Detection task and I've already implemented in Lasagne a complex structure which involves both Convolutional and Recurrent layers. The network **is quite big** and it gets trained **slowly** but results are good up to now and I predict a total of 5 classes with almost 80% of average f1-score.

All the Recurrent layers involved in the network use GRU units. However, doing some experiments I tried to replace them with LSTM. It was merely a replacement and I didn't modify any other parameters/settings of the network. However, something really unexpected happened: the network seems to not work at all. I've a drop of more than 40% in my average f1-score and even increasing batch_size or total number of epochs the network doesn't learn at all.

**How is it possible such a huge difference in the performances of the two different recurrent units? How could I face the problem?**

My intuition is that as the network is quite hard to train, maybe all the complexity that relies behind LSTM implementation doesn't allow the learning process? What should I monitor in the network?

Comment: Are you measuring performance on a per-parameter basis? A network with $k$ GRUs has fewer parameters than a network with $k$ LSTM cells.

Comment: @Sycorax what do you mean with per-parameter basis? Actually I've worked a little bit on the correct initialization of each parameter of the LSTM unit (weights and biases of each gate) but nothing seems to solve the problem.

Comment: I mean that if you're comparing performance of a model with $k$ parameters to a model with $100k$ parameters, you're comparing apples to orangoutangs.

Comment: I've just tried to reduce the number of units per LSTM layer, in such a way that now the total number of parameters of the models is more or less the same, but unfortunately there are no improvements. Actually, I also think it's a problem of complexity but I cannot figure out how to manage the issue properly.

Comment: If may help other desperate readers, once the two models were pretty much normalized by the number of parameters and after A LOT of hyper-parameters retuning, the performances started to be comparable. GRU outperforms LSTM but not dramatically, and a consistent difference in training time is visible.

Comment: It seems like you've found the answer to your question. You're not only allowed but encouraged to write up your answers to your questions!

Answer (score 1):

In comments, OP writes:

> If may help other desperate readers, once the two models were pretty much normalized by the number of parameters and after A LOT of hyper-parameters retuning, the performances started to be comparable. GRU outperforms LSTM but not dramatically, and a consistent difference in training time is visible.

---

I've copied OP's comment as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

- [Are we seeing a dramatic drop in answers per question?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question/5320#5320)
- [Comments that are actually answers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers)
- [We have a very large & widening gap between questions and answers. How do we fix it?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix)

Comment: This result is really interesting. It'd be nice to have a write-up, showing the hyper-parameters used and so on. Might even be paper-worthy, if well done. Certainly worthy of a blog post I reckon though. cc @arcticriki